# radius of circle inscribed in rectangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, rectangles

I have two circles inside a rectangle(4 * 6), where the diameter of one of both is the total length of a side of the rectangle, and the other circle diameter is part of the length of the another side.

This image resume all:
[image: trigonometry problem]

- What is the name of the theory behind this problem?
- How to find the radius R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Draw a line between the circle centers. Note that the length is exactly $R+2$. 
Thus:

$$(R+2)^2=2^2 + (6-R)^2$$
Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** note the right triangle below.  What does this tell you about $R$?

[image]